# groupby and for loop with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I'm newbie in python3, I was R user few month ago.
Here is the problem.
my dataframe(**df1**) somewhat looks like this:

```
   Date         quarter        number
2015-10-09          1           250
2015-10-09          2           400
2015-10-09          3           310
2015-10-10          1           300
2015-10-10          2           410
2015-10-10          3           280
    .               .            .
    .               .            .
```

Data are more than 5000. Above image is just few lines.
What I want is that the absolute difference numbers among quarter for every day.
The result dataframe which I want should looks like following frame:

```
   Date          absolute_interval
2015-10-09            150
2015-10-09            90
2015-10-10            110
2015-10-10            130
    .                 .            
    .                 .
```

I tried to use **df2=df1.groupby('Date')**.
And then I want to apply for loop.
my pseudo code is

```
for k in df2:
    for u in df2[k]:
```

But I don't think this will work, so I'm stuck in here currently.
Any Solution??
Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Does [`df.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) not work?

Comment: with R you could have done it `df%>%group_by(Date)%>%mutate(c(NA,abs(diff(number))))%>%na.omit()`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to sutdy python syntax.

Comment: @BallpointBen I didn't know df.diff exist....I will try thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pd.concat([df.Date,df.groupby('Date').number.diff().abs()],axis=1).dropna()
Out[608]: 
         Date  number
1  2015-10-09   150.0
2  2015-10-09    90.0
4  2015-10-10   110.0
5  2015-10-10   130.0
```

You can also do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: abs(x['number']-x['number'].shift(1))).dropna())

              number
Date                
2015-10-09 1   150.0
           2    90.0
2015-10-10 4   110.0
           5   130.0
```

You can add `.reset_index()` at the end if you need to